# How can I get this Collapsing Bar to display with my Google map?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Having issues with learning the ins and outs of flutter design... Anybody know how I can the Collapsing Navigation Sidebar to fit in with my Google Map? I'd like the map to be to the right of it. I also have some floating text widgets on top of my map in the form of stacks.  If I delete my Google map, the bar shows and works just fine. It's not visible with my map enabled.

```
return Stack(children: [
      Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0.0,
            backgroundColor: drawerBackgroundColor,
            title: Text(
              "Collapsing Navigation Drawer/Sidebar",
            ),
          ),
          body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: selectedColor,
            ),
            CollapsingNavigationDrawer(),
            Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: GoogleMap(
                    markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
                    initialCameraPosition:
                        CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: 10.0),
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    compassEnabled: true,
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                    mapType: MapType.normal,
                    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                      controller.setMapStyle(Utils.mapStyles);
                    }),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack takes multiple children and orders them from bottom to top. So the first item is the bottom-most and the last is the top-most. So place your map first and then the CollapsingNavigationDrawer

```
Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: GoogleMap(
                    markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
                    initialCameraPosition:
                        CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: 10.0),
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    compassEnabled: true,
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                    mapType: MapType.normal,
                    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                      controller.setMapStyle(Utils.mapStyles);
                    }),
              ),
              CollapsingNavigationDrawer(),
]
```